# Convert ambiguous grammar to unambiguous and SLR(1)

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers, ambiguity

I have the following ambiguous operator grammar:

```
E->E+E*E | E-E*E
E->E+E | E-E | E+E | E*E | E/E
E->(E) | x
```

I must convert it to an **unambiguous** one which is also **SLR(1)**. 
The following rules regarding precedence and associativity must hold:

- Operators * and / have the **highest** precedence (and precedence between them must be equal)
- Operators - and + have the **same** precedence (lower than * and /)
- All operators are **left** associative.
- Reducing with the first 2 rules is preferred if it does not break the precedence and associativity rules.

My problem is the first line of the grammar `(E+E*E , E-E*E)`. I can't find i way to convert it and the new grammar will be SLR(1).

Edit:
The closest i came is this grammar, but it has 2 SLR conflicts:

```
E->E+F | E-F | T
T->T+F | T-F | F
F-> F*C | F/C | C
C-> (E) | x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start where you probably started, with the classic expression grammar:

$$\begin{align}E&\to T\mid E + T\mid E - T\\
T&\to F\mid T * F\mid T / F\\
F&\to ( E )\mid x\\
\end{align}$$

and then we add the "fused" productions:

$$\begin{align}E&\to E + T * F\mid E - T * F\\
\end{align}$$

That grammar has a conflict because of the ambiguity:

$$\begin{align}E&\to E+T*F\\E&\to E+T \to E+T*F\end{align}$$
(and similarly for the $-$ operator).

So how to get rid of the ambiguity? Clearly, we don't want $E\to E+T$ to match $E+T*F$. So we need to define $$T' = T \setminus T * F$$ in order to be able to restrict the $E$ production to $E\to E + T'$.

Since the set difference operator is not valid in a CFG, we need to write the definition out the long way:

$$\begin{align}E\to&\;T\mid E + T'\mid E - T'\;\mid\\
&\;E + T * F\mid E - T * F\\
T'\to&\;F\mid T / F\\
T\to&\;T'\mid T * F\\
F\to&\;( E )\mid x\\
\end{align}$$